# I can't get binding parameter value in hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Postgres database I have data and I passing the string value in the query. I didn't get any error but the values are not retrieved why? what is the reason I don't know please help me

UserData.class

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
public class UserData {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
                                             
    private int userId;
                                               
    private String userName;
public UserData() {}
    public UserData(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
        
    }
    
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserData [userId=" + userId + ", userName=" + userName + "]";
    }
```

HibernateTest.class

```
package org.Dhiya.hibernate;

import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.javabrains.thila.dto.UserData;
public class HibernateTestt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
SessionFactory sessionFactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        String minUserId="5";
        String userName="User 10";
        
        Query query=session.createQuery("from UserData where userId > :userId and userName= :userName");
        query.setParameter("userId", Integer.parseInt(minUserId));
         query.setParameter("userName", userName);
       List<UserData> users= (List<UserData>)query.list();
        
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
           
            
           for(UserData user:users)
                
                System.out.println(user.getUserName());
}
}
```

console

```
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:13 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.24.Final
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:13 AM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb1]
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=postgres}
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 1 (min=1)
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:14 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.javabrains.thila.dto.TwoWheeler
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:15 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
WARN: HHH000139: Illegal use of @Table in a subclass of a SINGLE_TABLE hierarchy: org.javabrains.thila.dto.FourWheeler
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:15 AM org.hibernate.resource.beans.spi.ManagedBeanRegistryInitiator resolveBeanContainer
INFO: HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:15 AM org.hibernate.search.engine.Version <clinit>
INFO: HSEARCH000034: Hibernate Search 5.11.7.Final
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:15 AM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@3337d04c] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Dec 24, 2020 8:51:16 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: select userdata0_.userId as userid1_0_, userdata0_.userName as username2_0_ from UserData userdata0_ where userdata0_.userId>? and userdata0_.userName=?
```

I got the above output I didn't get any error but I didn't get string value also.
I'm waiting for your response Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are Few Hints,

1. Please Check with the table whether Data exists For given Inputs.
2. Fetch the Data then Cast it to **UserData** Object
3. Print For Loop Before Closing Session and commit.

Comment: If I give for loop for before session it will show an error Transaction not successfully started. what I do that

Comment: sorry, you are right I gave the wrong data in my string that is why I didn't get output. Now I got output. Thank you.